# Webpack DevServer rebuilds on change but browser doesn't get update signal

Tags: webpack

I've set up Webpack DevServer and when I change entry file it rebuilds the bundle but doesn't send any signal to Chrome (tested with multiple browsers). I've tried to find problem with disabling all plugings and modules but it didn't work.

So here is my webpack configuration file

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: "./src/app.js",
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },

    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'deterministic',
        usedExports: true,
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: "vendors",
                    chunks: "all",
                }
            }
        },
    },

    devtool: "eval-cheap-module-source-map",
    devServer: {
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "assets/css/app.[contenthash].css",
        }),
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/i,
            use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 
            {
                loader: "css-loader", 
                options: {importLoaders: 1},
            }, 
            {
                loader: "postcss-loader",
                options: {
                    postcssOptions: {
                        plugins: [
                            "autoprefixer"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }],
          },
          {
              test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)/i,
              type: 'asset/resource',
              generator: {
                  filename: "assets/img/[name]-[hash][ext]", 
              }
          },
          {
              test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
              type: 'asset/resource',
              generator: {
                filename: "assets/font/[name]-[hash][ext]", 
            }
          },
          {
              test: /\.(js)$/i,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                  loader: "babel-loader"
              }
          }
        ],
      },
}
```

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

According to [this PR](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/2758) this problem can be solved by removing `browserslist` setting or adding `target: "web"` to `webpack.config.js` to override `browserslist`.

```
target: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "web" : "browserslist"
```

Package versions

```
"browserslist": "4.16.3",
"webpack": "5.24.3",
```